# Trying to copy content from Excel to MS Word

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a content from excel into a bookmark in MS word. But I'm getting run time error 424. Kindly help me with it. I'm very new to Visual basics and programming as well. I have attached my code.
Thanks

```
Sub WordDoc()
Dim wrdApp As Object
Dim Number As String
Dim wrdDoc As Object
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("H:\IP Automation\createDoc.docx")
Number = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
Call InsBookmark(ID, Number)
End Sub


Sub InsBookmark(strBMName, strVariable)
If strVariable <> "" Then
If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(ID) Then
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(ID).Select
Selection.Delete
Selection.InsertAfter (strVariable)

End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: where is the error thrown?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't seperate this into two subs, as the word doc will not persist across them so "ActiveDocument" wont work.  just copy the code from the second sub into the first and replace `ActiveDocument` with `wrdDoc`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.  Give it a go and see how you get along.

```
Sub Export_Table_Word()

    'Name of the existing Word doc.
    Const stWordReport As String = "Final Report.docx"

    'Word objects.
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wdbmRange As Word.Range

    'Excel objects.
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rnReport As Range

    'Initialize the Excel objects.
    Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("PwC Contact Information")
    Set rnReport = wsSheet.Range("Table1")

    'Initialize the Word objets.
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path & "\" & stWordReport)
    Set wdbmRange = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Report").Range


    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In wdDoc.Tables
        tbl.Delete
    Next tbl


    'If the macro has been run before, clean up any artifacts before trying to paste the table in again.
    On Error Resume Next
    With wdDoc.InlineShapes(1)
        .Select
        .Delete
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Turn off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Copy the report to the clipboard.
    rnReport.Copy

    'Select the range defined by the "Report" bookmark and paste in the report from clipboard.
    With wdbmRange
        .Select
        .Paste
    End With

    'Save and close the Word doc.
    With wdDoc
        .Save
        .Close
    End With

    'Quit Word.
    wdApp.Quit

    'Null out your variables.
    Set wdbmRange = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

    'Clear out the clipboard, and turn screen updating back on.
    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    MsgBox "The report has successfully been " & vbNewLine & _
           "transferred to " & stWordReport, vbInformation

End Sub
```